# Sequelize - How to search in association in only one of the cases?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to search for 2 kind of entries :

- Pages that have pageType "generic"
- All pages that have pageType "specific" AND professionId equal to the parameter I'm passing.

Only way I found was to do two requests :

```
static getPagesForProfession(professionID) {
  return Promise.all([
    Page.findAll({
      where: {
        pageType: "generic",
      },
    }),
    Page.findAll({
      where: {
        pageType: "specific",
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: sequelize.models.Profession,
          as: "Professions",
          where: {
            id: professionID,
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]);
}
```

Is there a way to do it in one request ?

`Page` is associated to `Profession` in a Many to Many relation with a jonction table.

Comment: What association is between `Page` and `Profession`?

Comment: Many to Many with a jonction table.

Comment: You can try to move the condition `id: professionID` to Page's `where` option like `$Professions.id$`: professionID but I'm not sure if it will work. Anyway, such conditions on the table in M:N relationship would not be effective. Maybe you need to think of including a junction table and add this condition there.